# Testing Facebook Login using testcafe

Tags: testing, facebook-graph-api, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm currently encountering an issue with the Facebook Login app while running e2e tests using TestCafe. The app has been properly configured, and regular logins work without any problems. However, when TestCafe attempts to use the functioning link for Facebook Login, it throws an error as shown in this screenshot:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5gPr.png)

I'm wondering if there are any limitations or restrictions for using Facebook Login within automation tests. Could there be a problem with the app's configuration that's causing this issue?

I have updated testcafe to lastest version, updated facebook api version to 17, tried different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may be caused by necessity of using HTTPS. You can try one of the following ways to fix that:

- Use the [Native Automation mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode)
- Set the [hostname](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface?search#--hostname-name) option to `localhost`
- Specify the [SSL](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402839/guides/advanced-guides/test-https-features-and-http2-websites#test-https-websites) options